# Controlling electromagnets in clock display

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, electronics

I have an electromechanical 7-segment clock display with each segment controlled by an electromagnet. A segment is 'on' depending on the polarity of the last pulse to its electromagnet.

Can anyone advise how I could control the electromagnets via the GPIO pins so they turn on/off, as required, once a minute to change the time?

I imagine relays would need to be used. It's complicated because the polarity to each electromagnet needs 'swapping' to turn it on/off.

There are 28 electromagnets in all (7 x 4).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You will need H-bridges if you want to reverse the polarity. You can save quite a bit by organizing your solenoids in a matrix (e.g. 4*7) and using a half-bridge for each row/column, an detailed in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/125548/72179):

[image]

Comment: +1, ingenious idea. Nice you found it again.